# adding values of each key to its counterpart in multiple dictionaries / Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum

If I had multiple dictionaries in(/as indices of) a list called "year". And each dictionary had months abbreviations as its keys and the amount of rainfall under that month for the equivalent values. How can I add the amount of values so that in the end I have a list with one dictionary showing sum of rainfalls under each month.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post some examples of your dictionaries please ? And what you have tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean something like this:

```
dict_list = [{'a': 4, 'b': 7}, {'a': 10, 'b': 8}, {'a': 5, 'b': 6}]

final_dict = {}
for k in dict_list[0].keys():
    final_dict[k] = 0
for d in dict_list:
    for key, val in d.items():
        final_dict[key] += val

print(final_dict)
```